# How to connect php with IBM SQL Database using Bluemix?

Tags: php, cloud, ibm-cloud

Suppose, i am connect to mysql database using mysql_coni(), so that now i am try to connect IBM SQL Database which provide by IBM Bluemix.

Which function or which correct way used to connect PHP With IBM SQL Database within bluemix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect to the SQLDB service in Bluemix you can use db2_connect. 
You should use a connection string instead of separate database/username/pw/etc. parameters because it is a remote DB service

Following an example of parsing VCAP_SERVICES to connect to the SQLDB service in PHP:

```
# Decode JSON for DB connection parameters
$services_json = json_decode($json,true);
$sqldb = $services_json["sqldb"];
if (empty($sqldb)) {
    echo "No sqldb service instance bound. Please bind a sqldb service instance before";
    return;
}

$sqldb_config = $services_json["sqldb"][0]["credentials"];

// create DB connect string
$conn_string = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};";
$conn_string .= "DATABASE=" . $sqldb_config["db"] . ";"; 
$conn_string .= "HOSTNAME=" . $sqldb_config["host"] . ";";
$conn_string .= "PORT=" . $sqldb_config["port"] . ";"; 
$conn_string .= "PROTOCOL=TCPIP;";
$conn_string .= "UID=" . $sqldb_config["username"] . ";";
$conn_string .= "PWD=" . $sqldb_config["password"] . ";";

// connect to database
$conn = db2_connect($conn_string, '', '');
```

Comment: i am follow your code but i fetch error like :-  No sqldb service instance bound. Please bind a sqldb service instance before        plz help me

Comment: You have to bind the sqldb service to your application using bluemix console or cf CLI, then restage and restart the application

Comment: Is it possible to bind service without cf or CLI?

Comment: If you wish to use an instance of a service available on Bluemix you have to use Bluemix console or cf CLI to create and bind the service. The same for a custom service you would deploy on Bluemix. Otherwise if you wish to connect to an external service you can connect to it as usual

Answer (score 1):

Please see the accepted answer in this post : https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/20036/how-to-compile-php-with-db2-support-in-bluemix/