# How to connect to a SQL DB with PHP in Bluemix

Tags: db2, ibm-cloud

I am binding a service to my database and I found the following code online:

```
$services_json = json_decode($json,true);   <br/>
$sqldb = $services_json["sqldb"];    <br/>
if (empty($sqldb)) {   <br/>
    echo "No sqldb service instance bound. Please bind a sqldb service instance     before";   <br/>
    return;    <br/>
}    <br/>
     <br/>
$sqldb_config = $services_json["sqldb"][0]["credentials"];       <br/>
       <br/>
// create DB connect string   <br/>
$conn_string = "DRIVER={IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER};";                   <br/>
$conn_string .= "DATABASE=" . $sqldb_config["db"] . ";";     <br/>
$conn_string .= "HOSTNAME=" . $sqldb_config["host"] . ";";   <br/>
$conn_string .= "PORT=" . $sqldb_config["port"] . ";";     <br/>
$conn_string .= "PROTOCOL=TCPIP;";     <br/>
$conn_string .= "UID=" . $sqldb_config["username"] . ";";    <br/>
$conn_string .= "PWD=" . $sqldb_config["password"] . ";";     <br/>
   <br/>
// connect to database      <br/>
$conn = db2_connect($conn_string, '', '');       <br/>
```

I am not getting any response or I don't know db2_connect statement execute or not.

Please help me.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the fact that you are not getting any response? Are you seeing an error message?

Comment: Yeah, I execute db_connect() but i don't know successfully run or not and my php web page can't display anything.

Comment: Why does your php code have `<br/>`? You can view logs by doing `cf logs <appname> --recent`

Comment: This is likely a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32745721/how-to-connect-php-with-ibm-sql-database-using-bluemix

Comment: Yeah, but still getting a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to check your database which bind to your project or not using cf command or use gui also.

Comment: I do also still problem remaining.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if the connection was successful or not then add the following code after the db2_connect call:

```
   if ($conn) {
        echo "Connection succeeded.";
    }
    else {
        echo "Connection failed.";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

db2_connect returns false if connection failed, otherwise returns the connection resource to use.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.db2-connect.php

In case of error you can use 
db2_conn_err to get the error got in the last connecting attempt

Comment: i am also check db2_conn_err but it not give any error but i does not connect to database.    Happy 2 Help !

Comment: I guess your DB connection is working well. Have you tried with any query?